# Does anyone know how best to cope with floating point errors in the FFT calculation process?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, fft

Does anyone know how best to cope with floating point errors in the FFT calculation process? The problem is that these errors accumulate because of all the summations. They are especially annoying when computing the phase for a given frequency component:

atan(imaginary / real) can give quite a significant phase shift if both real and imaginary are tiny due to a floating point truncation, but of the same order.

The only solution I have come up with so far is to look at the maximum magnitude in the signal and disregard any frequency with a magnitude of under 1% of the maximum value and set it's real part to 0 so the phase comes out as NaN. However, this seems a little clumsy to me. Any better ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: The overall FFT error behavior is known to be well behaved, but have not seen any study or work with dealing with errors in individual components, particularly tiny ones. If one frequency component has a tiny magnitude, does it matter much what its phase is? Its contribution to the overall signal is also tiny, regardless of phase. If you are trying to isolate a particular frequency regardless of magnitude, maybe a custom filter could help?

Comment: Indeed, you need to ignore components with a small magnitude, they are dominated by rounding errors and also are irrelevant to the signal. Note that `atan(imaginary / real)` doesn’t give the phase, as it is limited to half the circle. Use `atan2(imaginary, real)`.